# Need to delete commas in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have got a problem to delete comma in string.
I tried `replace`, `substr`, `remove`, and `slice` and everything else I've found on the internet.

```
function reverseWords(str){
 var newstr = str.split(" ")
 newstr.reverse()
 var oldstr = newstr.toString()
 oldstr.replace(',','')
 return oldstr
 };
```

I should have `'world! hello'`, instead got: `'world!,hello'`

Comment: All you really need is to change the call to `.toString()` to `.join('')`

Comment: And `.replace()` does not modify the original string; it returns a new string. But you don't need to remove commas if you use `.join('')` because it won't add them in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign `oldstr` to the replaced version:

```
function reverseWords(str) {
  var newstr = str.split(" ")
  newstr.reverse()
  var oldstr = newstr.toString()
  oldstr = oldstr.replace(',', '')
  return oldstr;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the following: `oldstr.replace(',','')` does not modify the string, instead it returns new one.

So, correct code looks like this:

```js
function reverseWords(str){
 var newstr = str.split(" ")
 newstr.reverse()
 var oldstr = newstr.toString()
 return oldstr.replace(',','')
 };
```

Edit: actually, `reverse()` *does* modify the array (unlike `replace()`), and you don't need to use intermediate variable. Corrected the code.

Edit 2: as others have already noted, your main goal seems to be to reverse word order, not to remove commas (which are product of awkward array-to-string conversion). In that case, correct code would look like this:

```js
function reverseWords(str) {
    return str.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
 const reverseWords = (str) => str.split(" ").reverse().toString().replace(',','');
 
 console.log(reverseWords('world!,hello'))
```